# Example of a finite ring with identity containing a ring without identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-rings, rngs

What is an example of a finite ring $R$ with unity and a subring $S$ of $R$ that is not a ring with unity?

Comment: In general, finite or not: **any** ideal in **any** ring is a ring in itself, and if the ideal is *proper* then it cannot contain the parent ring's unit. For a rather boring generalization, the ideal $\{0\}\;$ in any non-zero ring will do.

Comment: @Don But the zero ring *is* a ring with $1,\,$ viz. $\,1 = 0,\,$ so it doesn't work here.

Comment: @BillDubuque, it is usually assumed, as far as I know, that $0\neq 1\;$ in any ring...but even if weren't, then we can talk of any "non-zero ring"...

Comment: @Don While definitions of [domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_(ring_theory)) and [fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)) often require $\,0\ne 1,\,$ this is not so common for rings, e.g. the Wikipedia article on the [zero ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_ring) states "The zero ring is the unique ring in which the additive identity $0$ and multiplicative identity $1$ coincide".

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer

Answer (score 4):

$\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$ is a unital finite ring, and the subring consisting of the elements $\{0,2,4,6\}$ is finite, but with no unit.

Comment: @kevin321 The simplicity of this (very good) example allows you to check things right away by hand. If you study *local rings* later on, you'll find that local rings don't have any idempotents other than $0$ and $1$. Since for each prime $p$ the ring $\Bbb Z/p^k\Bbb Z$ is local, none of the nontrivial ideals can have an identity. This creates a whole class of examples based on the same idea.